# Nginx logrotate not cleaning the logs

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, logrotate

I have this config for nginx logrotate

```
/var/log/nginx/*.log {
        daily
        missingok
        rotate 3
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        create 0640 www-data adm
        sharedscripts
        prerotate
                if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
                        run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
                fi \
        endscript
        postrotate
                invoke-rc.d nginx rotate >/dev/null 2>&1
        endscript
}
```

Ideally, it should compress file in gz and then remove the previous files after 3 days but here are my log files

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 1.4G Dec 10 00:00 2016-12-09-access.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 www-data adm         0 Dec 11 06:33 2016-12-10-access.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 1.5G Dec 11 00:00 2016-12-10-access.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 www-data adm         0 Dec 12 06:30 2016-12-11-access.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 1.6G Dec 12 00:00 2016-12-11-access.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 www-data adm         0 Dec 13 06:46 2016-12-12-access.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 1.4G Dec 13 00:00 2016-12-12-access.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 www-data adm         0 Dec 14 06:25 2016-12-13-access.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 1.4G Dec 14 00:00 2016-12-13-access.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 www-data adm         0 Dec 15 06:50 2016-12-14-access.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 1.5G Dec 15 00:00 2016-12-14-access.log.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 362M Dec 15 07:59 2016-12-15-access.log
-rw-r----- 1 www-data adm         0 Dec 15 06:50 ---access.log
-rw-r----- 1 www-data adm       254 Dec 15 04:53 ---access.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 www-data adm       202 Oct 25 03:58 ---access.log.10.gz
-rw-r----- 1 www-data adm       578 Oct 24 02:30 ---access.log.11.gz
-rw-r----- 1 www-data adm      1.3K Oct 23 06:11 ---access.log.12.gz
-rw-r----- 1 www-data adm       980 Oct 22 05:39 ---access.log.13.gz
-rw-r----- 1 www-data adm       648 Oct 21 05:59 ---access.log.14.gz
-rw-r----- 1 www-data adm      1006 Oct 20 05:45 ---access.log.15.gz
-rw-r----- 1 www-data adm       150 Dec 13 23:03 ---access.log.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 www-data adm        89 Dec 13 05:46 ---access.log.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 www-data adm       421 Dec 12 06:23 ---access.log.4.gz
-rw-r----- 1 www-data adm       277 Nov  8 17:16 ---access.log.5.gz
-rw-r----- 1 www-data adm       174 Nov  7 05:52 ---access.log.6.gz
-rw-r----- 1 www-data adm       104 Nov  5 18:42 ---access.log.7.gz
-rw-r----- 1 www-data adm       111 Nov  4 23:43 ---access.log.8.gz
-rw-r----- 1 www-data adm       220 Oct 25 19:36 ---access.log.9.gz
```

And logrotate status is

```
"/var/log/nginx/2016-12-01-access.log" 2016-12-2
"/var/log/nginx/2016-11-21-access.log" 2016-11-22
"/var/log/nginx/2016-09-16-access.log" 2016-9-17
"/var/log/mail.err" 2016-2-10
"/var/log/nginx/2016-10-06-access.log" 2016-10-7
"/var/log/nginx/2016-09-14-access.log" 2016-9-15
"/var/log/nginx/2016-11-02-access.log" 2016-11-3
"/var/log/nginx/2016-10-04-access.log" 2016-10-5
"/var/log/nginx/2016-10-22-access.log" 2016-10-23
"/var/log/nginx/2016-09-30-access.log" 2016-10-1
"/var/log/landscape/package-reporter.log" 2016-12-15
"/var/log/nginx/2016-10-20-access.log" 2016-10-21
```

Which doesn't give too much info regarding the recent days rotation.How can I debug the configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

You can debug particular script with -df parameter:

```
logrotate -df /etc/logrotate.d/nginx
```

and execute it immediately (if you need it):

```
logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/nginx
```

Note that there are often settings in the /etc/logrotate.conf file that apply to all logrotate scripts, so it may be necessary to run it in conjunction with your specific script:

```
logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf /etc/logrotate.d/nginx
```

*However* this config file usually calls ALL scripts under the logrotate.d folder, so you may want to comment this line out temporarily, or create a copy of this file for testing which excludes the directory call:

```
#include /etc/logrotate.d
```

Also read about **delaycompress** configuration option in the [man](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html):

> Postpone compression of the previous log file to the next rotation
> cycle. This has only effect when used in combination with compress. It
> can be used when some program can not be told to close its logfile and
> thus might continue writing to the previous log file for some time.

Comment: ran the -df, go http://chopapp.com/#7og0bsf . It is not considering access.log.1 files for deletion.

Comment: There is no access.log.1 in your ls listing. Debug ran properly, I dont see any problems. Try `dateext` directive with your logrotate config and remove date prefixes from log files names (like 2016-12-09-).

Comment: I mean not considering date-access.log.1 files for deletion as you shaw in te logs